# setting a quota on zfs doesn't work

Tags: freebsd, zfs, quota

I'm on FreeBSD 11. In order to set quota on my pool named storage, I enter these configs in terminal:

```
zfs set quota=10G storage
zfs set userquota@user1=1M storage
```

The problem is when I connect from samba or sftp, I can copy more than 1MB of file and the quota doesn't work.

Comment: What happens if you refresh from the remote side (F5 in Windows Explorer) or restart the Samba service? For comparison, I tested it on illumos and it works without a restart there, but the CIFS implementation is different from FreeBSD.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `zfs` manual page (FreeBSD 11-STABLE from 2017-03-09),

```
Enforcement of user quotas may be delayed by several seconds. This
delay means that a user might exceed their quota before the system
notices that they are over quota and begins to refuse additional
writes with the EDQUOT error message.
```

It's possible that your tests are exposing this behaviour. What happens if you attempt to exceed the value of `userquota` in several transactions, giving the system time to notice?